# Iterar um String array dentro de um objecto

Tags: java, android

Construí o seguinte objecto:

```
public class TableHelper {

    private String TABLE;
    private String[] COLUMNS;

    public TableHelper (String name, String[] columns){
        this.TABLE   = name;
        this.COLUMNS = columns;
    }

    // GETTERS
    public String name(){
        return TABLE;
    }

    public String[] columns(){
        return COLUMNS;
    }

    // SETTERS
    public void name(String name){
        this.TABLE = name;
    }
    public void columns(String[] columns){
        this.COLUMNS = columns;
    }

}
```

E estou a popular um `array` com um conjunto de `objectos` iguais ao de cima da seguinte forma:

```
public static List<TableHelper> tableList = Arrays.asList(
        new TableHelper("menu", new String[]{
                "id         PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT",
                "position   INTEGER",
                "active     INTEGER"
        }),

        new TableHelper("menu_languages", new String[]{
                "id         PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT",
                "menu_id    INTEGER",
                "language   TEXT",
                "title      TEXT",
        }),

        new TableHelper("submenu", new String[]{
                "id         PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT",
                "menu_id    INTEGER",
                "position   INTEGER",
                "active     INTEGER"
        }),

        new TableHelper("submenu_languages", new String[]{
                "id         PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT",
                "submenu_id INTEGER",
                "language   TEXT",
                "title      TEXT",
        })
);
```

O que preciso agora é de iterar o campo `String[] COLUMNS` dentro de cada objecto dentro do array. Para já tenho isto mas sei que está errado. Como posso conseguir fazer o que pretendo com recurso ao ciclo `for`:

```
for (TableHelper tables : Config.tableList){
    for(TableHelper col : tables.columns()){
        Log.e("COLUMN", tables2.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
for (TableHelper tables : Config.tableList){
    for(String col : tables.columns()){
        Log.e("COLUMN", col);
    }
}
```

Explicação:

- O tipo do retorno do seu método `columns` é `String` e não `TableHelper`. O compilador deve ter reclamado disso.
- No seu loop não tem nenhuma variável `tables2`. Mas mesmo que tivesse, a cada iteração você estaria logando sempre a mesma coisa, e essa coisa que não é o que você está iterando. Ou seja, não era o que você queria. O que você queria é a coluna que você está iterando, que é `col`.